# How do we start using Repast4Py

Tags: repast4py

I am pretty new to using Ubuntu, so I am not really sure how to start using Repast4py after downloading it. I've ran it before in repast simphony already and that worked fine, but how do I do it in python?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Repast4Py is not a stand-alone application. Rather, it's a python package (a collection of classes and functions) that you use to write a simulation as a python application. Typically, you'd use a code editor such as visual studio code to write the application, and then run it from the command line. The User Guide provides more details on how to run a simulation here:

https://repast.github.io/repast4py.site/guide/user_guide.html#_running_the_simulation

Comment: I am now having trouble running the code. I am using their command they provide mpirun -n 4 python examples/rndwalk/rndwalk.py examples/rndwalk/random_walk.yaml with python being replaced by python3, but it isn't really returning anything. How is the program supposed to be when I run it? It doesn't give me an error message, but are there multiple things im supposed to run consecutively or something?

Comment: You should see the data logged by the model in an output directory. The User Guide has the details.